# Git submodules in sibling folder

Tags: git, git-submodules

I like some of the features of git submodules.  However, [IntelliJ does not use them well](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-64024).  I just need a parent git repo that will point to a list of child repos that I use.  I think IntelliJ will cooperate if all of the child repos are in sibling folders in the filesystem.

I tried this:

git submodule add me@myserver/child1.git ../child1

Got this:

```
The following path is ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
../child1 Use -f if you really want to add it.
```

Then I did this:

git submodule add -f me@myserver/child1.git ../child1

and got:

```
Cloning into '../child1'...
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
fatal: Not a git repository: ../child1/../../.git/modules/../child1
```

Is there a way to add submodules as sibling folders?

Comment: Sure: don't make them submodules and use batch files or a custom program to manage the clone(s).

Comment: I believe git doesn't support this. What about creating normal submodule and then creating a symlink to whatever location you need.

Comment: I don't think symlink or Batch is an option.  Some users of this repo use windows some Linux.  Maybe gradle..but it seems like a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Here the issue is not so much the "sibling" part, but the .gitignore part: you want to create a submodule folder in a parent folder test1 which is ignored.

Also make sure ../xxx is still part of your parent repo (and not "one folder" above the root folder of that repo).
The folder `../child1/../../.git/modules` should exist.

A simpler process would be to go to the root folder to the main repo, and add from there:

```
cd /path/to/repo
git submodule add -f me@myserver/child1.git test1/child1
```

Comment: There is no .gitignore file in the repo.  If the git repo is in a subfolder, IntelliJ blows up.  I *think* it will work if the subfolder is a sibling.  Also, sorry for the confusion, but one of the errors said "test1" in my original question..it should say "child1" (I edited the question to fix it).

Comment: @User1 to check that, you can type (from where you were trying to add your submodule): `git check-ignore -v -- ../child1`

Comment: Cool trick.  It says `fatal: ../child1: '../child1' is outside repository`.

Comment: @User1 You need to add a submodule with a path which remains in the parent repo.